# How do I import function signatures to Ghidra?

Tags: windows, decompilation, ghidra

I'm working with an .exe which imports the old DirectX DLL DDRAW.DLL. The problem is, Ghidra doesn't know about it and shows all imported DDRAW functions as having no parameters. I know, I can edit functions to add the paramaters and define the missing datatypes, but I expect there's an automatic way to do it. Is there an option to simply load ddraw.h from the DirectX SDK and import all the function signatures and types?

Answer (score 7):

"File" -> "Parse C Source..." ... then parse the ddraw.h

But warning it doesn't work as smooth as expected. I could only get small headers to parse correctly.

A good video about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u15-r5Erfnw

Maybe you could ask that guy on Github to include the ddraw.h into his data type collection: https://github.com/0x6d696368/ghidra-data/tree/master/typeinfo